# Return the value of pointer using doublepointer

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void createAndFillList(int** ptr,int ninput){
    int i;
    ptr=malloc(sizeof(int)*ninput);
    for(i=0;i<ninput;i++){
        printf("enter: ");
        scanf("%d",&*(*ptr+i));
    }
    printf("%p\n",&*ptr);               
}

int main(){
    int** ptr;
    int ninput;

    printf("enter how many spaces will be allocated:");
    scanf("%d",&ninput);

    createAndFillList(ptr,ninput); 
    printf("%p\n", &ptr);       

    getch();
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

How to return the value of the address of the first `ptr` or `ptr + 0`? I tried everything and it seems to crash every time I input more than 1.

Comment: `&*(*ptr+i)` is bogus. You cannot take the address of an expression.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should declare a normal pointer in the `main` function, and then use the address-of operator `&` when calling the function. Then inside the function you use the dereference operator `*` when using the pointer-to-pointer.

So in `main`:

```
int *ptr;

...

createAndFillList(&ptr, ninput);
```

And in `createAndFillList`:

```
*ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * ninput);
...
    scanf("%d", &(*ptr)[i]);  /* Or `(*ptr) + i` */
```